# C Pointers about the different data type

Tags: c, pointers

Pointer always stores a integer value i.e address so why do we need to declare them with different data type.

Like

```
int a=3,*p=&a;
char c=r,*cha=&r;
```

why can't we do like

```
int *c;
char r=a;
c=&r;
```

Comment: An address need to be an integer value.

Comment: "Pointer always stores a integer value" --> Only valid addresses can be stored in a pointer, not necessarily all integer values covert properly to a pointer.  Also pointer to integer conversion has its limitations too.  Especially if `intptr_t` is not defined or code attempts to convert a function pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Essentially it's because

1. *Pointer arithmetic* would not work if the pointer types were not explicit.
2. The *pointer to member operator* would not work for `struct` pointer types.
3. The *alignment* requirements for types can differ. It might be possible to store a `char` at a location where it's not possible to store an `int`.
4. The sizes of pointers are not guaranteed to be the same by the C standard: i.e. `sizeof(int*)` is not necessarily the same as `sizeof(char*)`. This allows C to be used on exotic architectures.

Comment: Also struct pointers need to know the members they can point to.

Comment: @Barmar: Pinched that. That reason, along with the pointer arithmetic one are probably the two most important.

Comment: 1. is not completely right as stated. Untyped pointer could assume object size of 1 as do compiler extensions that allow pointer arithmetic with `void *` like gcc. So untyped pointer do not make arithmetic impossible, they only do them unwieldy as one would have to include the implicit `sizeof *p` explicit.

Comment: 2. is also not completely true when one knows how it was in the beginning of the C compilers at AT&T. The field names of a struct were in the global name space (now they are in the struct's namespace) and they represented an offset from the beginning of the structure. The field name was in fact nothing more than a constant (what nowadays would be `offsetof(struct x, field)`). `a->b` is lowerd to `*(a+b)` anyways, so there is nothing preventing pointer arithmetic here.

Comment: 3. This one is solid.

Comment: 4. True. Harvard architectures with separate memory spaces and some mainframes have really strange pointer rules.

Comment: Regarding 4, the C standard states that any pointer type may be converted to another pointer type and back again, without losing information. In practice this means that they will have the same size, or otherwise this C standard requirement will be very hard to fulfil.

Comment: @Lundin Detail: The round tripping of pointers does not apply to conversion to/from pointers between pointers to objects and pointers to functions.  Further the round tripping of object pointers is through `void*`.  `int*` to `char *` to `int*` need not work - it can lose information. C11 6.3.2.3 1

Answer (score 1):

To pass to the "user" of the pointer information about what kind of data the pointer points to. Basing on that it will/may depend how the pointed data will be interpreted and handled. Any time you can use a pointer to void, in this case that information is not available. Then, the user of that pointer should know from other sources what is pointed and how to work with it.

Comment: "Any time you can use a pointer to void" --> A pointer to a function may not fit in a `void*`.  `void*` is not a universal  pointer type for all, but is universal for pointer to objects.

Comment: Correct, I have left a bit freedom to interpret the words ))

Answer (score 1):

Batcheba has already 4 good reasons. Let me give some less important ones:

- function pointer and data pointer are not even compatible according to the standard ([Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) with separate code and data address spaces, memory models of [segmented](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Memory/lecture.html) architectures, etc.).
- the optimizer can exploit the fact that pointer on different types generally do not overlap and can elide a lot of memory loads that way (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing)

Comment: Do feel free to copy the 4 reasons from my answer, order to end up with a comprehensive answer.

Comment: No, it's ok that way. I wouldn't want to free ride on your answer which is good. I commented a little on them to because I'm an annoying nitpicker :-) but it's ok as it is.

Comment: But you raise some very good points in my answer comments. And I'll be sure to upvote a comprehensive answer from you.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *c;
char r=a;
c=&a;
```

In your declaration a is just a character not a variable. 
A pointer when defined can only store  the address of a specific type of variable. If you declare c as int *c, the pointer can only point on variables of type integer.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can assign an address value to any type pointers.

```
int d;
char* cp = (char*)&d;     // OK
float* fp = (float*)&d;   // OK
```

But when you get content from the address, you MUST know the type. Otherwise the compiler will not know how to interpret it.

Comment: `float* fp = (float*)&d;` is not OK, it is a strict aliasing violation and undefined behavior if you attempt to use the pointed-at data. [What is the strict aliasing rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Comment: @Lundin I don't know about strict aliasing violation. Which compiler has this action?

Comment: All standard-compliant compilers have it. Although only gcc is known to actively abuse strict aliasing for optimization purposes. For example, code like `int a = 123; *(float*)&a = 0.0f; if(a != 123){ printf("%d", a); } else { puts("a not changed"); }` might print "a not changed".

Comment: A pointer to `int` and one to `float` may have different alignment requirements.  `float* fp = (float*)&d;` is not OK.